# Xamarin Android app crashes on launch in release mode works fine in debug mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Android app crashes in the release mode after launching for the first time and works perfectly in debug mode.
I have disabled progaurd,shared runtime options and changed the 'link sdks' to "None". Added all the required architectures. Please find the logcat of the issue.

[image: Android app options screenshot]

```
 Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 010000b4 from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader' in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.InnerInvoke()<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Application.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__60.MoveNext()<d9bc55848bcb4df0a2fb5a602398b130>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Application.get_Properties()<d9bc55848bcb4df0a2fb5a602398b130>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Application.<SetPropertiesAsync>d__66.MoveNext()<d9bc55848bcb4df0a2fb5a602398b130>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Application.<SavePropertiesAsync>d__46.MoveNext()<d9bc55848bcb4df0a2fb5a602398b130>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.<OnStateChanged>d__39.MoveNext()<f839f54bae5d4fa09455747fadfaf940>:0
Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0()<bb8f3789d62b420bb7b0ae22e1ff3c26>:0
Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run()<bb8f3789d62b420bb7b0ae22e1ff3c26>:0
Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)<bb8f3789d62b420bb7b0ae22e1ff3c26>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.43(intptr,intptr)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 010000b4 from typeref (expected class 'System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader' in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.InnerInvoke()<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Application.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__60.MoveNext()<d9bc55848bcb4df0a2fb5a602398b130>:0
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run()RunnableImplementor.java:30
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:739
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:95
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:135
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5221
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()Method.java:372
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:898
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:693
```

Comment: Please share your android app settings.

Comment: I have edited my question and added setting image.Please help me in solving the issue.Thank You!

Comment: Check shared runtime options and link SDK only and try

Comment: tried both didnot work

Comment: Have checked all the system images to run an application?

Comment: APP works when I install the release apk from diawi but crashes when I install it from playstore and launch for first time. Later app works as usually.

Comment: Try Right click on Droid Project -> Property -> Android Option-> Linker -> "SDK Assemblies Only" and check

Comment: Am unable to build when I check sdk assemblies.Please find the logcat.  "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\name\Git\Tt\Droid\obj\Release\60\android\assets\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: May be the version of assemblies versions are vary. You need to find and fix it.

Comment: I have changed Linker to "SDK Assemblies only" still app crashes in release mode